# inputNumber primefaces no funciona

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Usando primefaces version 6.0, tengo mi formulario (inputText, dataTable, selectOnemenu,etc) y funciona correctamente, pero al momento de agregar un 
**p:inputNumber** me deja de funcionar todo Primefaces, es decir (inputText, dataTable, selectOnemenu,etc) que antes funcionaban, dejan de funcionar...en el log no aparece ningun error

```
<p:panelGrid  columns="2" layout="grid" style="border: none" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-6,ui-grid-col-6">
    <p:outputLabel value="Tamaño" style="width: 100%"></p:outputLabel>
    <p:inputNumber value="#{reporteadorBean.index2}" maxlength="15"  >
    </p:inputNumber>
    <p:outputLabel value="Tipo de dato" style="width: 100%"></p:outputLabel>
    <p:selectOneMenu>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione" itemValue="Seleccione" noSelectionOption="true"> </f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="String" itemValue="String"> </f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Date" itemValue="Date"> </f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Numeric" itemValue="Numeric"> </f:selectItem>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <br/>

 </p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Si pones el código (no es necesario todo, intenta hacer *un ejemplo lo más simple posible pero que cause el problema que te afecta* -puedes coger ideas de https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), igual te podemos ayudar. Si no, es prácticamente imposible que podamos dar una respuesta.

Comment: Muestra el fragmento de código que presenta el error, y ve probando uno a uno, por ejemplo el inputNumer con solo el InputText y ve si funciona  y así puedas detectar que componente falla y porque, puede ser algún problema de ajax,etc ..

Comment: ya agregue el fragmento del codigo, nuevamente reitero que funciona correctamente sin el inputNumber...
<p:inputNumber></p:inputNumber> si se encuentra solamente declarado tampoco funciona, no es la variable del Bean

Comment: ¿Está dentro de un `h:form`?

Comment: si, se encuentra dentro de un h:form

Comment: El código se mira bien, en tu Bean el atributo que recibe el valor del inputNumber, cómo está declarado e inicializado ?

Comment: private int index2;
tiene su getter and setter

Comment: pero en teoria, solo con haber declarado el inputNumber deberia funcionar, es decir deberia mostrar una caja de texto en la vista, independiente de si tiene o no un "Value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según las [extensiones](http://snapshotshowcase-primeext.rhcloud.com/sections/inputNumber/basicUsage.jsf;jsessionid=FE5333C1CB049ACF1308C6BA4D44F26C) de primefaces ud debe usar la etiqueta `<pe>`:

```
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
```

aparte de

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

como tiene la version 6 le recomiendo esta [dependencia](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/wiki/Getting-Started)

ejemplo:

```
 <pe:inputNumber value="#{BB.valor}" rendered="#{row.isUpdatable(fecha)}" >
                <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{BB.changeValor(fecha, row, i)}" />
 </pe:inputNumber>
```

Suerte!!!

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas agregar la siguente linea en el encabezado de la pagina:

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

Con esto ya podrás obtener las cajas que sean para números